# Angularjs show select box dependent another select box

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS 1.3.

In a form with 3 select boxes, from the choosen option of the first one i will show only south or only north select box.

In my try below i got erros like completely disappear the content below.

Wich will be the best way using angularjs to show only one of the two boxes ?

```
<select name="Type" ng-model="data.Type">
  <option value="2">South</option>
  <option value="3">North</option>             
</select>

<div ng-if="data.Type==3">
  <label class="item item-input item-select" >
    <div class="input-label">North</div>
      <select name="South" ng-model="data.South">
          <option value="1">Dallas</option>
          <option value="2">Miami</option>
      </select>
  </label>
</div>

<div ng-if="data.Type==2">
  <label class="item item-input item-select" >
    <div class="input-label">South</div>
      <select name="North" ng-model="data.North">
        <option value="1">New York</option>
        <option value="2">Boston</option>
      </select>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: What did the errors say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me as-is with a very basic controller ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/8ajcmugL/)).

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('someController', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {} 
});
```

The reason you only see one dropdown defaulted to blank is that there is not an initial value specified for the `ng-model` in this case `data.Type`. But it does work as in the 'North' and 'South' values are also there and selecting one of them causes the next dropdown to appear.

If you initialise `data.Type` to '2' in the controller then the dropdown will be defaulted to 'South' and one of the other dropdowns will appear.

You may also want to set initial values for `data.North` & `data.South`.

[Fiddle with those updates](http://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/oknrbeLu)

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('someController', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        'Type' : 2,
        'South' : 1,
        'North' : 1
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you @sheilak it is working i only change to data.Type!=2 so i always see north as default.